# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent (without express and bodyparser)

Tags: node.js, post

I am trying to send http post with params like `{name: myname}`

Backend code is:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

        ...
        case "POST":

            if(request.url === "/api/user/delete"){

                //response.end('{}');
                var body = '';
                request.on('data', function (data) {
                    body += data;
                    // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
                    if (body.length > 1e6) {
                        // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
                        response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}).end();
                        request.connection.destroy();
                    }
                    else{
                        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                        response.end(JSON.stringify(qs.parse(body)));
                    }
                });
                request.on('end', function () {
                    // use POST
                    var POST = qs.parse(body);
                    console.log(POST); //log shows '{'{myname}':''}' i need output like {name:myname}


                });
            }
      ...
```

Comment: The `data` event can be triggered more than once.

Comment: Well, you're calling `response.end(JSON.stringify(qs.parse(body)));` with your first chunk of data. The next chunk will error, since you've alrady sent a response. That's kind of expected behaviour. But without the "kind of" part.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should send the response on `end` event of request to avoid re-sending responses as `data` event can occur multiple times.

If you really need to send on `data` event itself add a check for `headersSent` on `response` object

```
request.on('data', function(data) {
 body += data;
 // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
 if (body.length > 1e6 && !response.headersSent) {
  // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
  response.writeHead(413, {
   'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  }).end();
  request.connection.destroy();
 } else if (!response.headersSent) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
  response.end(JSON.stringify(qs.parse(body)));
 }
});
```